# How to get Ubuntu installed after deleting Windows and with no other OS present?

Tags: installation, downloads

I spent the night trying to get rid of my Windows XP operating system and around midnight I discovered a way to get rid of it. The problem is while I did get rid of the operating system, I hadn't yet found a way to get Ubuntu to do a proper download and install. So my dilemma is that I now have a laptop that when turned on says `Operating System not found.` Any ideas?

PS I did try Pendrive Linux to download it and attempted to install it with the CD. The night before I did try and do it directly from the website but it kept getting interrupted.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Please provide details as to the problems you are having.  Without specific error messages, it is difficult to know why you are having a problem.

Comment: @fossfreedom These are very similar question. OP's question is a bit more specific to when there are no other OS present.

Answer (score 5):

You will need another computer with an operating system and internet connection to download the Ubuntu ISO image from http://www.ubuntu.com.

Press the Start Download button to begin downloading from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Choose 32bit version if your computer has less than 4GB of memory (RAM).

Once the ISO is downloaded, [burn the ISO file into a CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-windows) or [create a bootable USB drive](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

Now take this CD or USB drive back to your computer and [boot from the CD or USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD#BIOS_is_not_set_to_boot_from_CD_or_DVD_drive).

Choose **Try Ubuntu** and make sure the display, sound, and internet works.

click on Install Ubuntu icon to start the [installation](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-desktop) when you are satisfied.

The more general question of how to install Ubuntu is answered in greater detail here: [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Hope this helps