# LiveCD hangs when removing boot CD for burning another

Tags: live-cd, burning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Ubuntu installed after deleting Windows and with no other OS present?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179144/how-to-get-ubuntu-installed-after-deleting-windows-and-with-no-other-os-present)

I downloaded an image of 12.04 and I want to burn it onto a CD.

Apparently each time I boot to the 10.10 LiveCD and try to burn the image using the default application (Brasero disc burner), when I replace the LiveCD with the empty CD, the system freezes.

What do I need to do so the system doesn't freeze and lets me burn my image?

Comment: I think this is by design, it's a Live CD right? Try making a Live USB and booting from that as a workaround, or do the 12.04 disc burn from whatever OS you have installed.

Comment: i have no OS installed, that is the rub

Comment: And can you make a Live USB?

Comment: @TomBrossman removing the Live USB will also cause this. I think the cause is, you can't run Ubuntu from noting

Comment: I don't think, this is a duplicate of the linked posted above. The question is quite different imo

Comment: @Anwar my suggestion is to boot a Live USB, download the ISO, and burn it to disc. Booting from USB frees the disc drive for burning. OP has no OS installed, so the solution at the possible duplicate will work. It isn't clear if they are *never* intending to install an OS and *always* use Live discs/USB, but that would be strange. If this is what they want then maybe it's not technically an exact dupe but it is quite similar. Still unexplained is why anyone needs to make a Live CD once they have a Live USB made.

Answer (score 3):

Tom is correct in that when using Ubuntu from a Live CD, you must keep the Ubuntu Live CD in the drive the entire time.  You basically have two options:

1- If you have and can connect a second CD/DVD drive, you can run the Ubuntu Live CD from one drive and burn with the other.

2- Create a Live USB (again, as Tom mentioned).

Answer (score 2):

There is a 3rd option, you could buy an official cd from Canonical http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17

Answer (score 2):

You were running Live CD, so removing that CD means, ***you were telling your computer to run Ubuntu from nothing!!!***, which your computer simply can't. It needs the data from the Live CD.

This situation is somewhat similar to removing Windows installation disk while installation is running. Of course, the installation will be stopped or hanged.

More technically, the contents of Live CD's are not fully mapped or loaded into the RAM or Main memory (which you may have been assuming). The contents are loaded into memory as per requirements. For example, Gparted program will not load into the memory until you start it from the Live CD. This type of loading is called [dynaming  loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) and is considered very essential.

I suggest you to save the downloaded iso file in another directoy in your PC or in the USB drive. (If you are using Live Ubuntu from USB and your USB has more space, you can save the iso file in that USB drive too. Though you need to be root to copy it)

Then transfer the file in another PC to burn the CD or if you have Windows, burn the CD with windows tools.

Comment: an option to map the ubuntu disk to memory would be nice

Comment: yeah. But Then your PC will become very slow and it is not an efficient way to use memory. The requirements to run Live CD will go too high .